# InvalidArgumentException Unable to locate a class or view for component [input-error]

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade, breeze

The exception I'm getting is when I access the chirps @ http://localhost:8000/chirps which should display a form from a Blade file. This actually is a step that I'm following as instructed in Laravel's bootcamp tutorial at https://bootcamp.laravel.com/blade/creating-chirps. Everything worked as expected until this point. I verified that the router is correctly routing the request, and could even display a test message(plain text without blade template) that I placed in index.blade.php which helped me isolate the issue to the blade template code present in index.blade.php. I reinstalled Laravel Breeze, but that didn't help. Please have a look at my controller and blade files to detect the issue.

web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ChirpController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

Route::resource('chirps', ChirpController::class)
    ->only(['index', 'store'])
    ->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
    
require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

ChirpController.php

`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Chirp;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class ChirpController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(): View
    {
        return view('chirps.index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Chirp  $chirp
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Chirp $chirp)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Chirp  $chirp
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Chirp $chirp)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Chirp  $chirp
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Chirp $chirp)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Chirp  $chirp
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Chirp $chirp)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

index.blad.php

```
<x-app-layout>
    <div class="max-w-2xl mx-auto p-4 sm:p-6 lg:p-8">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('chirps.store') }}">
            @csrf
            <textarea
                name="message"
                placeholder="{{ __('What\'s on your mind?') }}"
                class="block w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm"
            >{{ old('message') }}</textarea>
            <x-input-error :messages="$errors->get('message')" class="mt-2" />
            <x-primary-button class="mt-4">{{ __('Chirp') }}</x-primary-button>
        </form>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

I tried reinstalling Breeze with the following commands

php artisan breeze:install

php artisan migrate
npm install
npm run dev

This didn't help render the form in index.blade.php

Comment: the `x-input-error` component is not being loaded/found by the framework

Comment: How to ensure it loads?

Comment: ensure your `resources/views` directory has this file first

Comment: views directory doesn't have any file named x-input-error. Is it a blade file? Where can I download them from?

Comment: yes it is a blade file, the breeze install command (assuming you are using the blade stack) should copy these files in the views directory, and you should have there a `input-error.blade.php` file. did you maybe change stacks?

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in using blade templates. I ran "breeze install" a few times along the way from the beginning of this Laravel bootcamp tutorial. https://bootcamp.laravel.com/blade/creating-chirps. All steps have been carefully followed. Still, I'm facing this issue. Please offer some possible solutions.